# How can I create an Access / Audit log for the entire 500 user google enterprise domain?

Tags: google-email-audit-api

We have a situation at our office where we are trying to determine the IP address of where our users have logged in from at home, over the past 4 weeks.

In an ideal situation I just want something like this, which I can request back several days or weeks, or hopefully even months..:

`Email/Username   |   Logged in on    |  Public IP Address
joe@domain.com   |  May 27th - 16:46 |  192.168.1.3 
suzy@domain.com  |  May 27th - 16:47 |  192.168.1.9
billy@domain.com |  May 27th - 16:50 |  192.168.2.13`

(with actual public IP addresses instead of the private ones I'm making up for this example)

I've spoken with Google support for ideas and they turned me to here. 
I have already tried Flash Panel and Promevo and they weren't able to produce this type of information.

Any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the email audit API for login activities.  It actually shows you the IP addresses of the machines your user log in from.

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-audit/#downloading_account_information_files

Additionally, you can use a third party client called Google Apps Manager to easily retrieve this information for your users (https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-manager/wiki/ExamplesAccountAuditing#User_Account_Activity)